# What's the best storage method?

Tags: hardware, data, data-storage

I was wondering about what's the best storage method to save files to in order to save it from natural dynamics like *earthquakes*, *tsunamis*, or just to keep them along times...

We all know that there are several of storaging types such as:

- HDD, SDD
- Memory cards (SD,MMC)
- Flash drives (like USB, RAM and ROM)
- EEPROMs (well, that's for pretty sure not for a large amount of data)
- Magnetic tapes

Note that for storage method I mean actually archiving some files, without needing the possibility to actually have access to them, excpect in case we grab the storage device out of his safe place.

Also note that they actually should be powered off. So a RAM-like storage solution is not effective at all, cause it will loose its content once powered off.

I'm not planning any anti-catastrophe method to save my files ( *lol* ), I'm just asking it because actually I don't know which is the best one for archiving files in long time.

Comment: While an interesting / practical question in a lot of ways, really from an EE point of view the huge number of variables and evolving manufacturing processes make it really hard to expect a definitive answer on what's best under a particular set of circumstances.

Comment: HDDs and tapes will be destroyed by any length of time under floodwater. Memory cards will not, provided you clean them up, but have a finite lifetime (decade?) as charge leaks across the gates. Home-written optical media may or may not be chemically stable in the long term and should be kept in the dark. Pressed optical media lasts a long time as long as you don't scratch it. None of these is particularly fire-resistant.

Comment: Bonus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbiter_Image_Recovery_Project NASA kept the _tapes_ just fine since the 60s, but finding hardware to get the data off became a serious problem. Similar projects apply to early Voyager data, the BBC Domesday book (idiosyncratic Laserdisc format), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Record your files onto a gold record.

For extra security put them on a spaceship, and launch them out of the solar system. Will last a very long time.

[image]

Comment: +1 although the only problem with that record is that once some alien race discovers we've sent them Chuck Berry tracks they'll probably nuke us from orbit.

Comment: Ahaha nice tough, but I wasn't talking about so extreme cases :P

Comment: @DenysVitali You used the word "apocalypse" in your question. That is about the most extreme case imaginable. In an apocalypse, even in the case of EMP attack, anything electronic is dead. If you write a poor question you are going to get answers you can't use.

Comment: Well, maybe I've gone in a too deep case, I'll correct my question a bit

Comment: Found out the solution: [5D discs](http://www.engadget.com/2016/02/16/5d-discs-can-store-data-until-well-after-the-sun-burns-out/)